# Making DIV container fitting into parent TD

Tags: html, html-table

I'm hardly trying to make a DIV container fitting and resizing according to the parent TD and not according to the content of the DIV.
Here's what I want to achieve:

- The parent Table should always fit into screen, therefore the width is set to 100%
- The left column is fixed size to display the menu
- The right column (content) should resize according to browser width
- In the content TD, I use the DIV tag for scrolling the content table (overflow auto)

**I've expected the DIV to scroll the content (horizontally) and resize its width upon the parent TD. But the DIV extends and the IE scrollbars are used instead of DIV scrollbars.**

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="200px" />
            <col width="*" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width:100px;">
                    Left header
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                right header
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Menu
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- this DIV should scroll! -->
                <div style="overflow:auto; width:100%;">
                    <table border="1" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                SOME_LONG_COLUMN_VALUES_SOME_LONG_COLUMN_VALUES
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                SOME_LONG_COLUMN_VALUES_SOME_LONG_COLUMN_VALUES
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It might be possible to do so with a layout using DIV tags only. But due to the given master page layout and the asp:GridView, I cannot change that. 
Also it should still work with old IE6.

Can somebody help me please?

### Update

Could solve the problem myself. If someone is interested, here's the solution:
added the CSS style `table-layout:fixed;` to the root table.

Comment: Please tell us in simple  what you want in result ?

Comment: Hello, I expected the DIV to always fill the parent TD width. If I resize the browser, the DIV should also grow or shrink.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the width="100%" be on the TD entry instead of the child div and grand-child table?

Like?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<body> 
<table border="1" width="100%"> 
    <colgroup> 
        <col width="200px" /> 
        <col width="*" /> 
    </colgroup> 
    <tr> 
        <td> 
            <div style="width:100px;"> 
                Left header 
            </div> 
        </td> 
        <td> 
            right header 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td> 
            Menu 
        </td> 
        <td style="width:100%;> 
            <!-- this DIV should scroll! --> 
            <div style="overflow:auto; width:100%;"> 
                <table border="1" width="100%"> 
                    <tr> 
                        <td> 
                            SOME_LONG_COLUMN_VALUES_SOME_LONG_COLUMN_VALUES 
                        </td> 
                        <td> 
                            SOME_LONG_COLUMN_VALUES_SOME_LONG_COLUMN_VALUES 
                        </td> 
                    </tr> 
                </table> 
            </div> 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```